# Asp.Net Core 2.0 HTTP -> HTTPS on Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am learning Web-Based Programming and currently chose to work on Asp.Net Core 2.0. 
I had successfully created a Web App with 2 layers of Controllers Home & API. 
The Home Controller interacts directly with my Views while the API controller is called using GetAsync, PostAsync, PutAsync, etc. from my Home controller.
Recent I decided to move this app into HTTPS. Learned about self-signed certificates and had successfully gotten it to run except my API becomes inaccessible.

With SSL switched off, I could still call my API with Postman.

I used to call my API using this URI: http://localhost:5667/api/WebApi.

```
  var response = client.GetAsync(“SomeApi”)
    response.Wait();
```

Now I tried using URI: https://localhost:5667/api/WebApi but breaks at `response.Wait().`

Any advice, please. Thanks in advance

As requested: here’s a portion of my Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(
   options =>
   {
       options.SslPort=5667;
       options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    }
 );

 services.AddAntiforgery(
  options => 
  {
        options.Cookie.Name=“_af”;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy=CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.HeaderName=“X-XSRF-TOKEN”;
     }
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP and HTTPS cannot be served over the same port.  If your localhost HTTP endpoint is on 5667, then likely your HTTPS endpoint is on 5668 - though you can check the port number for yourself in the info that Kestrel will log on startup.

In production, HTTP is typically served over port 80, while HTTPS is served over port 443.  These are the defaults if you don't specify otherwise.

Separately, you might want to consider enabling [HTTPS redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl) in your `Configure` block:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: I am moving away from HTTP altogether. So the main app is listening on HTTPS too and not a combination of HTTP and HTTPS. Thanks for you quick response. 

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the relevant startup code.  Otherwise one can only make such assumptions.

Comment: I am on my mobile right now and in a train. Will do so once I arrive office. Thanks Matt Johnson

Comment: I suspect a context synchronisation problem, but i can't tell if you don't show us the code in your api side.